Wordpress How to track the active Loco Translate File
I use Loco Translate and like to know if there is a way to track the active Loco Translate file of a translated text piece on the frontend? For example using the Inspect tool in Chrome?

Why not ask the developer of the plugin? https://localise.biz/contact
